Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': Unexpected end of JSON input
(Why is 'Hello' always cut away from the text rendition? Anyways... Hello!)
I'm struggling to find the cause of a
'Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': Unexpected end of JSON input'
error I'm getting with .json() in the React code below, whether the array in the model is parsed or stringified. The response I get from the console.log(fetchList); is:
Response {
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3000/"
[[Prototype]]: Response
}

I threw in a console.log inside the controller's getAllTopics() function and nothing gets printed, which suggests the request never even reaches the controller?
(Also the async is here only because eventually this is going to connect to a real database and not a mock like now.)
I have a test tomorrow and I can't move on without having this problem solved! Any idea? :) Thank you!
function TopicContainer () {

  const [topicList, setTopicList] = useState([])

  const serverURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

  async function fetchData () {
    const fetchList = await fetch(serverURL);
    console.log(fetchList);
    const fetchListParsed = await fetchList.json()
    setTopicList(fetchListParsed);
  }

  useEffect(() => {fetchData();}, [])

  return (
    <div className='topic-container'>
      {topicList.map( topic => <Topic key={topic._id} title={topic.title} pubAt={topic.published_at} score={topic.score}></Topic>)}
    </div>
  )

}

Here's my express index...
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = require('./router');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
// app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

...router...
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const control = require('./control')

router.get('/', control.getAllTopics);
  
module.exports = router;

...controller...
'use strict';

const model = require('./model');

exports.getAllTopics = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const topicList = model;
    res.status(200);
    res.json(topicList);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('Error retrieving from the database');
    res.status(500);
    res.json(err);
  }
};

...and model.
'use strict';

const db = [
  {
    _id: "sdk92k20elked202doe2",
    title: "Porting from Angular.js to Angular 2",
    published_at: "2017-01-08T21:00:11.620Z",
    score: 5
  },
  {
    _id: "sdk92k20elked202doe3",
    title: "'Being on the edge' by John Middleware.",
    published_at: "2017-01-20T09:00:11.620Z",
    score: 5
  },
  {
    _id: "sdk92k20elked202doe4",
    title: "Porting from Angular.js to Angular 2",
    published_at: "2017-01-08T21:00:11.620Z",
    score: 5
  }
];

module.exports = db;


Open up your browser's developer tools' Network tab and select that network request, then look at its Response tab to see what your browser is getting back from the server. Or change the .json() to .text() and console.log() it to see if it looks like proper JSON or a HTML error message.

Provided I'm looking at the right request (and I think I do), the response is completely empty. There are actually 3 of those.

And this here is the entirety of your code? Do you see the "Server running on port ..." message? Is it possible that you have an older version of the server still running in the background (check what is listening on port 3000)?

omfg I had forgotten to start running the server... thank you so much
